Phaser framework - attach child objects to the Actor
I'm developing my first simple game using Phaser 3 framework.
I have class Enemy (extends Actor class). Inside constructor I create two objects - Arc and Text. This two objects should be attached to every Enemy and move together.
export class Enemy extends Actor {
    constructor(
        scene: Phaser.Scene, x: number, y: number
    ) {
        super(scene, x, y, 'enemy')
        this.x = x
        this.y = x

        const circle: GameObjects.Arc = this.scene.add.circle(x, y, 20, 0x333333)
        const elSizeText: GameObjects.Text = this.scene.add.text(x, y, 'label, {font: 'bold 20px Arial'})

        this.scene.physics.add.existing(this)
        this.setVelocity(0, 500)
    }
}

I've implemented that by creating container and including all 3 objects inside.
this.container = this.scene.add.container(x, y)
this.container.add([circle, elSizeText, this])

The problem is that now if I need to change (or get) the position of the Enemy I should change this.container.x, this.container.y. It seems more natural to change this.x and this.y instead.
Is there any more correct way for implementing attachment of child objects to the Actor class?

I would rather extend from Phaser.Container instead of Actor or  the Actor class should extend from Phaser.Container and pack all gameObjects into the container. Then you can move the object with x or y.
An alternative would be to override the preupdate method and than set in there the position.
(I'm not sure, if this is a good solution)
export class Enemy extends Actor {
    ...
    preUpdate (time, delta) {
        super.preUpdate(time, delta);
        this.container.x = this.x;
        this.container.y = this.y;
    }
}

